# Create a button in VF page that creates a new case with certain record type

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, case

I want to create a button in my VF page that when clicked on creates a new case with a certain record type or at least takes you to the new case page with the record type already filled in. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

creating new case, just join button with method:

```
public class some controller{
   publis PageReference createCase(){
       Case case = new Case( RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id 
                                             FROM RecordType 
                                             WHERE SobjectType = 'Case' 
                                                 AND DeveloperName = 'Record Type Name'
                                             Limit 1].Id,
                             /** required fields **/
                           )
       try{
           insert case;
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
        /** some actions  **/
       }
       return new PageReference ('/' + case.Id);
   }
}
```

This will create new case with selected RecordType and redirect user to this case. Here I used query, but in my oppinion it is better to store it in some class as static varible.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a simple `URLFOR` tag together with an `$Action` global variable:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Case.NewCase)}" value="Create a case"/>
```

This button redirects user to the record type selection page (only if you have any) and then to the new case page layout.

Comment: Great this approach works fine. But what if I want to do a "Save & New" on a child record. The new child record loses the information about his parent record, if you know what i mean. This would solve my problem here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41887/custom-save-new-button-with-redirect-to-record-type-selection-page